# Loading header.php on specific page

Tags: php

(**TL;DR** available below)

I'm using the Divi theme and I run into a problem. I'm using the Gravity Forms plugin to generate a form with a multi upload. This multi upload seems to use Ajax which from my little testing seems to confront with Divi.

(I put the CDN in dev mode and deactivated all plugins, the upload button/ drag and drop still didn't work).

The solution for this problem is a little code snipped:

```
gravity_form_enqueue_scripts( 2, true );
```

before the opening `<?php`  and the beginning of the `wp_head(); ?>`. This, however, conflicts with the full-width Divi header on desktops. In the sense that the "scroll down button" doesn't work anymore and the image also isn't full screen anymore. On mobile, it still works.

**TL;DR**

The theoretical solution with which I could come up is to only load the required `header.php` on said page. I did google around a bit and found code snippets but I couldn't get it to work due to lack of instructions or wrong implementation on my end.

So, some guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Added the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I got it working. I just had to create a copy of the `header.php` in my child theme, rename it and add `if(is_page(XXXX)) { get_header('header-name'); } else { get_header(); }` after the initial `<?php` in the `page.php` of my child theme.